# Why have to connect to mongdoDB remotely via ssh?

Tags: mongodb

I have a strange prolbem.I install mongoDB on my intranet server(RedHat 7.0) ,which ip is 192.168.0.253,and connect successfully on localhost in server command line, then I set the bind_ip=0.0.0.0 in the conf file ,create authorization user and use compass to remotely connect to my mongdodb server,like this 
[I had fill the hostname(server ip 192.168.0.253, port:27017),my PC's ip is 192.169.0.110,choose authentication,fill username and password ,which I had create in mongodb via localhost connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t88R.png)

Finally it failed connection.
at last ,I choose ssh tunnel and fill in the RedHat server ip，username and password,unexpectly it success.I feel so stange.why do I have to use ssh tunnel to remotely connect the server? please anyone can help? so apprecaited.forgive my so-so english

Comment: Have you configured the firewall in the server to allow access to port 27017 from external sources? If SSH works, this sounds like a networking setup issue to me.

Comment: thanks for your answer,I disable the SElinux ，reboot my server and finally it works.